# Выполнение javascript-кода при изменении размеров окна браузера

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно вызывать javascript-код:

1. после загрузки страницы
2. при изменении размеров окна браузера

Вот этот код работает для первого случая и почему-то не работает для второго:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(doSomethingUseful());
});

function doSomethingUseful() {
  $('body').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called. ' + document.body.clientWidth + '</div>');
}
```

А вот этот работает для второго случая, но не работает для первого:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called. ' + document.body.clientWidth + '</div>');
  });
});
```

См. два тестовых примера ниже - их можно скопипастить, сохранить и запустить.

Какой код будет работать для обоих случаев?

**Дополнено из комментариев.**

Тестовый пример 1:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>resize</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(window).resize(doSomethingUseful());
    });

    function doSomethingUseful() {
      $('body').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called. ' + document.body.clientWidth + '</div>');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>hello world :)</div>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Тестовый пример 2:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>resize</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(window).resize(function() {
        $('body').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called. ' + document.body.clientWidth + '</div>');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>hello world :)</div>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в первом примере не указываете функцию обработчик события size, а вызываете ее. Замените `$(window).resize(doSomethingUseful());` на `$(window).resize(doSomethingUseful);` в первом примере и все заработает.

Comment: ага и еще надо добавить вызов doSomethingUseful() после загрузки страницы, вот так:

<html>
<head>
 <title>resize</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   doSomethingUseful();
   $(window).resize(doSomethingUseful);
  });

  function doSomethingUseful() {
   $('body').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called. ' + document.body.clientWidth + '</div>');
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div>hello world :)</div>

 <hr>

</body>
</html>

и все работает Ж) Спасибо :)

Comment: Если я ответил на Ваш вопрос, то нажмите на серую галочку в кружочке, чтобы отметить данный ответ как правильный. Она находится, под "пальцем вниз" возле начала ответа.

Answer (score 4):

**Зачем** использовать в подобных случаях jQuery?

```
window.onresize = func; // при изменении размеров браузера
window.onload   = func; // при загрузке страницы.
```

Я понимаю, jQuery многофункционален и удобен, но есть случаи когда он излишен, а творение рук программиста с его использования - огромнейший **костыль**.